# Different ways to manage windows profile location

Tags: windows, profile

We recently moved to FSLogix profiles.  My profile had a disaster were it deleted all my files from the file server rather than moving them to the new profile - warning to others doing this.

We have workstations that use the FSlogix profiles, and servers that use local profiles.  On the servers there is something that is still pointing my profile at the old fileserver that we used for our roaming profiles.

Where is that configuration stored?

At the moment if I log into any server I get a dialogue about
Windows cannot access
\old server that no longer exists\userfiles\users\Desktop
When I login, and then if I try to access any file I get the same issue.  Changing the location of the desktop to the default location, does not work... It goes through the steps asks to move everything and then goes back to the above dialogue.

I have tried looking in group policy and seeing if there is something in my policy, but have not yet found what is setting the desktop/profile location.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve was to
Create a new user with the same permissions and with out the X years of legacy settings.

The other way was changing the location on the individual machine.
It hangs for a long time
Told it not to move files and then skip all
And sign out and back in again.

Still no idea how to identify where in the settings the old profile path was coming from.